# JDBC Oracle Database, what do numbered parameters in prepared statement mean?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I inherited a Java codebase that interacts with an Oracle DB via oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver. The queries that currently exist look like the following:

```
UPDATE my_table SET col_1=?1,col_2=?2 WHERE SUBSTR(col_3,1,28)=?3 AND col_4=?4
```

I have never encountered parameter numbering like this in an SQL query before. Is this just to enhance readability or does oracle.JDBC actually use them to name the parameters or something?

Update: Thanks to @Andreas and @chsdk, I poked around more. It looks like my driver is actually not Vanilla JDBC, but oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: That is not valid JDBC syntax. You must be using a persistence framework that builds on top of JDBC. I've seen that before, but can't remember which framework/helper was doing it like that.

Comment: I think this query is generated from `JPA` or `Hibernate`' code, when you write a `JPQL` or `HQL` query it generates a similar query.